# Looking for NSOparation derived downloader

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Does anyone know of a good example to write an asynchronous downloader, for IOS6 that's NSOpeartion based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example of operation based networking is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Its a library so they dont explain how its all done, but its a very good example of how this sort of thing should be done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to download a URL, I suggest QHTTPOperation. Google it up - it's part of a bunch of Apple code samples.